# Flutter switching between current location and user entered location to show weather data

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, flutter-provider, openweathermap

When launched initially, my app goes to a Getting_City_Name page to get the city name(gets lat,long from the city name) and then to a home screen which displays the data. The user can change city by going back to Getting_City_Name page. I want to show the weather data of the current location when the app launches, instead of going to a page to get the city name. How can I do that?
Note: I already have a function to get current latitude and longitude using the geolocator plugin. I just need to send those values as default to the Future that gets weather data from openweatherapi.

Current Implementation:

Scaffold body of Home Page where the weather is displayed:

```
Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Consumer<CityProvider>(
                    builder: ((context, value, child) => Text(
                          value.cityInfo!.name.toString(),
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color:
                                  myColor.secondaryColor.withOpacity(0.7),
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 35),
                        )),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 7,
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                    child: Consumer<CityProvider>(
                      builder: ((context, value, child) => Text(
                            details.localizedName.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontSize: 20,
                                color: Color.fromARGB(255, 100, 86, 86)
                                    .withOpacity(.4)),
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Consumer<CityProvider>(
                  builder: ((context, value, child) => Text(
                        '${DateFormat('EEE, MMM d, hh:mm aaa').format(value.weatherInfo!.time)}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 20,
                            color: Color.fromARGB(163, 87, 89, 90)),
                      ))),
```

Provider Class

```
class CityProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  CityInfo? cityInfo;
  WeatherInfo? weatherInfo;
  PollutionInfo? pollutionInfo;
  List<FiveDayForcastData> fiveDayData = [];
  
  List<double> minTemp = [];
  List<String> iconString = [];
  List<DateTime> time = [];
  List<String> day = [];
  List<String> date = [];
  //date chnages(i.e 10/11 becomes 10/12) on jth terms)
  List<int> j = [0, 5, 13, 21, 29];
  List<int> degreeofWind = [];

  Future<void> cityName(String cityName, lat, lang) async {
    cityInfo = await gettingCityData(cityName);

    notifyListeners();
  }

  Future<void> gettingTheWeather(lat, lang) async {
    weatherInfo = await gettingWeatherData(lat, lang);

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Basically I need to pass the lat, long values from geolocator plugin as default in the gettingWeatherData function and later pass the lat, long values from the city names entered by the users.

Weather Function

```
Constants myConstaints = Constants();

Future<WeatherInfo> gettingWeatherData(lat, long) async {
  var url = Uri.parse(
      'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=$lat&lon=$long&units=metric&appid=${myConstaints.apiKey}');
  var response = await http.get(url);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return WeatherInfo.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else
    throw Exception('failed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as I understood you want to get the data initially and pass it gettingWeatherData function.
Alright I don't what your structure is but simply you need to apply this logic in initState function if you using Stateful Widget or directly after build method if you using Stateless or Stateful it doesn't really matter.

```
// you this code in your build method before returning Scaffold widget or in initState function
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      provider= Provider.of<CityProvider>(context, listen: false);
      provider.gettingTheWeather(lat,lng);
    });
```

And simply you can handle this case using **bool variables and notifyListeners** as the possible easiest way for that.

Hope this answer could bring you what you need.